# Get only parent categories wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm trying to create a category list, but i only want to list the parent categories and not the child categories. How can i do this? so far i've created a list, which list all parent and child categories.

```
function categoryList() {


  $args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
  );
$categories = get_categories($args);

  $output .= '<ul class="category-list">';
  foreach($categories as $category) { 
          if ($category){
          $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';
          }
  } 

  $output .= '</li>';
  $output .= '</ul>';

  return $output;

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By parent categories, I assume you mean top-level categories. This is actually documented on the [Codex page for `get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories#Get_only_top_level_categories): You should call `get_categories` with `parent => 0`

```
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'parent' => 0
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
```

Comment: the strange thing is i have 3 parent categories with no childs and one parent category with 3 childs. however when i add above it onnly shows the parent category with chidls

Comment: That is strange! I don't really know what could be the issue then. Perhaps you should unaccept my answer so that someone else can chime in.

Answer (score 4):

List only top-level (parent) categorizes in wordpress. The option  'hide_empty' => 0 makes sure to list even empty top-level categories.

```
        $args = array(
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'parent'   => 0,
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                //'exclude'   => '7',
                // optional you can exclude parent categories from listing
         );

        $categories = get_categories( $args );
```

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
$categories = get_categories( [ 'parent'=> id_parent ,'hide_empty' => 0,] );
```

Comment: When adding an answer to a five year old question with three existing answers it is very important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 0):

A native Wordpress solution to return the CURRENT parent category, 
excluding unwanted categories:

```
function primary_categories($arr_excluded_cats) {

if($arr_excluded_cats == null) {
    $arr_excluded_cats = array();
}

$post_cats = get_the_category();

$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'parent' => 0
);

    $primary_categories = get_categories($args);

    foreach ($primary_categories as $primary_category) {

        foreach ($post_cats as $post_cat) {
            if(($primary_category->slug == $post_cat->slug) && (!in_array($primary_category->slug, $arr_excluded_cats))) {
                return $primary_category->slug;
            }
        }
    }
}

//if you have more than two parent categories associated with the post, you can delete the ones you don't want here
$dont_return_these = array(
        'receitas','enciclopedico'
    );

//use the function like this:
echo primary_categories($dont_return_these);
```

Comments:

- if you only have one parent category by post, pass null instead of array
- if you want another output instead of slug change this to return $primary_category-> slug;

Answer (score 0):

The code below will give us the parent cat name and the URL.

```
function ns_primary_cat() {
  $cat_now = get_the_category();
  $cat_now = $cat_now[0];
  if ( 0 == $cat_now->category_parent ) {
     $catname = '<span class="category"><a href="' . get_category_link( $cat_now->term_id ) . '">' . $cat_now->name . '</a></span>';
  } else {
    $parent_id = $cat_now->category_parent;
    $parent_cat = get_category( $parent_id );
    $catname = '<span class="category"><a href="' . get_category_link( $parent_id ) . '">' . $parent_cat->name . '</a></span>';
  }
  return $catname;
}
```