# Get primary category if more than one is selected?

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, how can I revert to the primary category?

I'm using the following loop, if all three are checked then it just reverts to the last term. I want to make sure it's the primary category.

```
<?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category', array("fields" => "names"));
foreach ($term_list as $term) {
    $name = $term;
} ?>
```

[image]

Comment: will primary be always on top

Comment: @lazyme114 Not necessarily, can see where you were going with that. I guess to be safe it shouldn't be done that way.

Comment: worth a try i was thinking this

    foreach($term_list as $term) {
            $name[] = $term;
    }
    echo $name[0];

Comment: @lazyme114 I'll give it a go, not much options really.

Comment: here a solution to a similar question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/57996959/6036169](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57996959/6036169)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is not a native wordpress feature, but a feature of Yoast SEO ([see here](https://yoast.com/yoast-seo-3-1/)).

You can check for primary status the following way:

```
<?php
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category', ['fields' => 'all']);
foreach($term_list as $term) {
   if( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category',true) == $term->term_id ) {
     // this is a primary category
   }
}
?>
```

If you are using custom taxonomies, use the meta_key

```
_yoast_wpseo_primary_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY
```

instead.

Comment: Ah, that would explain the lack of documentation! I'll give that a go and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this usefull code snippet! If I'm not wrong when getting term list the 3rd paramter should be array("fields" => "all") otherwise you just get the names of all terms and can't compare the term_id when looping through the $term_list. At least when I tried it was like that.

Comment: The comment by @Luckyfella is correct - the above code won't work as is. You need to change array("fields" => "names") to array("fields" => "all"). You can't compare a string to an ID value

Comment: Thanks for notice, fixed.

Comment: I don't think this solution works anymore in the new Yoast SEO version.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using "The SEO Framework" plugin instead of "Yoast SEO":

```
$taxonomy = 'category'; 

$post_id = get_the_ID();

$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, $taxonomy, ['fields' => 'all']);

$primary_term = intval(get_post_meta( $post_id, '_primary_term_' . $taxonomy, true ));

foreach($terms as $term) {

   if( $primary_term == $term->term_id ) {

        // this is a primary category
   }
}
```

References:

https://github.com/sybrew/the-seo-framework/blob/4262ea703eaaa50813d8cd4ac13f4537b5c6a4cc/inc/classes/post-data.class.php#L633

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the plugin "Yoast SEO":

```html
yoast_get_primary_term_id( 'product_cat', $post->id );
```

Comment: Since Yoast 3.2, there are 2 functions available:

[`yoast_get_primary_term_id()`](https://wordpress-seo.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/yoast_get_primary_term_id/) and 
[`yoast_get_primary_term()`](https://wordpress-seo.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/yoast_get_primary_term/)

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer won't work if you used Yoast plugin indexing and optimization.

```
$wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( 'category', get_the_id() );
$wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
$term = get_term( $wpseo_primary_term );
```

This would be correct way to do it.

To make sure site doesn't break if Yoast gets disabled you should wrap the code in

`if ( class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term') ) { }`

Comment: This method worked for me with newer version of Yoast. Seems a lot cleaner than running a for each to check against every category on every post. My only addition would be to include: if (is_wp_error($term)) { } so you can tell if there is no primary set.

Comment: This tutorial may also be worth taking a look at: https://joshuawinn.com/using-yoasts-primary-category-in-wordpress-theme/

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using [Rank Math SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-by-rank-math/) plugin, you can use:

```
get_post_meta( $post_id, 'rank_math_primary_category', true );
```

Related post: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-primary-category-2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get primary category

```
<?php
function prefix_get_primary_category($post_id) {
  if(class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term')) {
    $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( 'category', $post_id );
    $wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
    $the_primary_term = get_term( $wpseo_primary_term );

    if(!empty($the_primary_term) && !is_wp_error($the_primary_term)) {
      return $the_primary_term;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```