# Loading and showing child categories only when clicking on parent category

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site of a client and from the wp-admin, there are around 10k categories.

The main problem is everytime I come to make a new post or edit a post, it is loading all parent and child categories in the Setting category area for that post, so it is slowing down the site tremendously.

So I was just wondering if there is any way, that we just load the main parent category every time we create or edit a post, and then when we select on 1 parent category it will show child categories at that time. Eventually, it just loads and shows when we click on parent category and not right from the start.

Does anybody have the solution for this? I would be appreciating your idea and solution.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: i have searched a solution for you but i have not checked that by my self. Please check this url https://wordpress.org/support/topic/only-show-parent-category-in-drop-down/ .If it works then please let me know i will provide you next step after this

Comment: this is not my intention. My intention is when you try to create a new post or edit a post, there would be category area on the right so you can set the category for the post. But I dont this cagetory area to show all, it just load the parent category first and then when we choose 1 parent category it will show the child categories... Because if is loading right away from the start, it is slowing down my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you following steps for your specific issue.

1. **Remove Categories dropdown from sidebar** Remove this default dropdown from right sidebar so that your page speed increases.You can follow this url to remove your current categories filter https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37633/how-to-remove-categories-filter-from-wordpress-admin. You need to use **load-edit.php** hook for this
2. **Add your custom categories dropdown** You need to add custom meta box in which you will display only Parent categories in dropdown.You can get parent categories by getting help from this url [Get only parent categories wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859947/get-only-parent-categories-wordpress). Once you retrieve parent categories in dropdown or in div then you need to apply ajax when user clicks on any Parent category then loads its child categories in another dropdown or below the parent category

So this is my perception i think you can achieve your target using this technique

Comment: yes this exactly what I was intending to do. Even though you dont have detailed things to do on step 2 but I already know what I have to do from your outline and methods. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ok thanks . If along the way, I hit something I will ask you :)

Comment: Sure buddy.I will be there for you